# Disable Vagrant globbing of boxes

Tags: vagrant

Is there a way to disable "vm globbing"? That is to say if i have two vm's, `:dev`, and `:prod` defined in a Vagrant file, and I run `vagrant reload`, I want vagrant to refuse to perform the command because I did not specify a box.

For clarities sake, my setup is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  config.vm.define :dev do |dev|
  end

  config.vm.define :prod do |prod|
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following at the top of your Vagrantfile, updating `VALIDATE_ACTIONS` with the actions for which you want to require a VM. Note that this will still allow the command `vagrant destroy` (without a specified VM) if there is only a single VM defined.

```
# Actions to validate
VALIDATE_ACTIONS = [ 'halt', 'destroy' ]

# Override default actions to check machine list
class ValidateCommand < Vagrant.plugin(2, :command)
  class << self
    attr_accessor :delegate_action
  end

  def initialize argv, env
    super(argv, env)
    @argv = argv
  end

  def execute
    vms = []
    with_target_vms(@argv, :reverse => true) do | machine |
      vms << machine
    end
    if vms.size > 1
      puts 'Please specify a single VM'
      1
    else
      with_target_vms(@argv, :reverse => true) do | machine |
        machine.action(ValidateCommand.delegate_action)
      end
      0
    end
  end
end

# Wrap validate command in plugin and invoke for overridden actions
class ValidatePlugin < Vagrant.plugin(2)
  name "Validate"
  VALIDATE_ACTIONS.each do | action |
    command action do
      ValidateCommand.delegate_action = action
      ValidateCommand
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it.